# Where can I get a copy of timeit.exe for Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Timeit.exe is part of the Windows Server 2003 Resource kit, and Microsoft's [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657) suggests that it is only compatible with 2003 and specifically does not work on 64-bit systems.

Which Microsoft package contains the 2008 version of it that is compatible with 64-bit systems?

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the `Measure-Command` cmdlet in PowerShell.

For example: `Measure-Command {Start-Process ProgramName -Wait}` where program name is the program or command you want to time.

[Using Measure-Command | TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176899.aspx)

[timeit.exe and windows 7 64 bit](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproappcompat/thread/7bb68c32-8a8c-4c59-918f-86a407bd2aa8/)